# Is there a way to allow users to run Azure DevOps pipelines, but not allow them to edit?

Tags: azure-devops, permissions, azure-pipelines, user-permissions

I'm running some Azure DevOps build pipelines for my team, and I want to be able to give my team members the ability to manually trigger the pipelines, but I don't want to give them the ability to edit them.

I've gone through the project permissions, one by one, and it looks like there's nothing that would allow for the desired behaviour, but I'm hoping I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is "Edit build pipeline" permission. Check this link: [Set different levels of pipeline permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops)

[image]

Comment: @Gwynnion If set this permission to "Deny", the Edit button should disappear.

Comment: Mistook that one for a different permission I had set to Deny at the project level (Edit project-level information). 

Works. Thanks!